# How to find data in JSON with unique keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have a JSON file, with several thousands records, which looks like this:

```
{
    "001": [18.180555, -66.749961],
    "002": [18.361945, -67.175597],
    "003": [18.455183, -67.119887]
}
```

Each `key` is unique. The `value` is an array containing latitude and longitude. Given a specific `key`, I want to extract latitude and longitude.

Without knowing the most efficient way (since there are tens of thousands of records), I am trying use something `filter` method.

```
let findKey = "002"
myJSON.filter(/*magic*/)
```

Also, I found to handle the situation when `key` is searched which is not present. For example, if `findKey = "004"`, how can I check it?

Comment: You can use `data[findKey]`. (It doesn't look like JSON, but a JS object. unless you're parsing it somewhere)

Comment: lat: `data[findKey][0]` and long `data[findKey][1]`

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm reading a `.json` file, and it got parsed as valid JSON.

Comment: @decpk This worked. Please add the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the element by using `bracket notation` to get the element as:

```js
const obj = {
  "001": [18.180555, -66.749961],
  "002": [18.361945, -67.175597],
  "003": [18.455183, -67.119887],
};

let findKey = "002";
if (obj[findKey]) {
  const lat = obj[findKey][0];
  const long = obj[findKey][1];
  console.log(lat, long);
}

let findKey2 = "004";
let lat2, long2;
if (obj[findKey2]) {
  lat2 = obj[findKey2][0];
  long2 = obj[findKey2][1];
  console.log(lat2, long2);
}
```

You can also use array destructuring also:

```js
const obj = {
  "001": [18.180555, -66.749961],
  "002": [18.361945, -67.175597],
  "003": [18.455183, -67.119887],
};

let findKey = "002";
const arr = obj[findKey];
if (arr) {
  const [lat, long] = arr;
  console.log(lat, long);
}

let findKey2 = "004";
const arr2 = obj[findKey2];
if (arr2) {
  const [lat2, long2] = arr2;
  console.log(lat2, long2);
}
```

Comment: Can you please add how to check for `findKey="004"`? This key does not exist and program crashes.

Comment: @Farhan that could look something like: *if(typeof arr != 'undefined') { do stuff } else { handle error }*

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
[lat, lng] = myJSON[findKey]
console.log(myJSON[findKey], lat, lng)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can deconstruct directly to the needed variables:

```js
const obj = {"001":[18.180555,-66.749961],"002":[18.361945,-67.175597],"003":[18.455183,-67.119887]};

const [lat, long] = obj?.["002"] ?? [,]
console.log(lat, long)

const [nLat, nLong] = obj?.["004"] ?? [,]
console.log(nLat, nLong)
```

Answer (score 1):

here's my code where you can get the values if exist and 'not exist' for the undefined key

```
const obj = {
    '001': [18.180555, -66.749961],
    '002': [18.361945, -67.175597],
    '003': [18.455183, -67.119887],
};

const find_key = '002';
const [lt, lg] = typeof obj[find_key] == 'undefined' ? ['not exist', 'not exist'] : obj[find_key];

console.log(lt, lg);
```